# Spring MVC @Valid annotation for all controllers?

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

Iv'e seen this nice mechanism:

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-jsr303-valid-example/

Is it possible to make the @Valid annotation avaialble for all the Controllers with validation? It seems very redundant to do the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getPlayerAccounts", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
public QueryResultsDTO<PlayerAccountResultDTO> getPlayerAccounts(@RequestBody **@Valid** FilteredQueryRequestDTO filteredQueryRequestDTO,
                                 **BindingResult result**) {

**this.validateDTO(result);**
return this.playerService.getPlayerAccounts(filteredQueryRequestDTO);
}
```

Reduandant code:

**@Valid**

**BindingResult result**

**this.validateDTO(result);**

These seems like a recurring pattern, probably someone already solved it? maybe with aspects?
I dont care that all my methods and controllers will have the @Valid login, most of the DTOs they recieve will be valid anyway (since no validation annotations are applied to them)

Thanks

Comment: You sure can do it with aspects. But I am not sure wether this is really worth the hassle.

Comment: So you think validating in each controller is a better solution? Thinking about a developer that forgets to add @Valid annotation make me feel dizzy

Comment: Well, that's what unit tests are there for...

Comment: OK, but you still didn't resolve the code redundancy issue

Comment: I don't see it as an issue. Each layer of abstraction adds complexity, complexity tends to come with bugs and problems.

Comment: It would cost you more time dealing with how to get rid of the "redundant code" then just typing a the few words that you consider redundant. ps: if you consider that piece of code redundant half of the Java syntax could be considered redundant.

Answer (score 3):

you cannot omit @Valid annotation, since this is the way to tell spring which dto to validate, that is just the way the spring validation works. But having a BindingResult result to each of your methods is not necessary. You may omit it completely. If you want to do something when validation fails, you can catch the `MethodArgumentNotValidException` that is thrown in that case from an exception handling method (e.g you can use a class with `@ControllerAdvice` annotations that will contain `@ExceptionHandler` methods applied to all controllers - exception handling is a whole different topic, you can read more details on related [spring mvc exception handling documentation](http://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc))

Comment: Don't know if things changed since '14 but I could ommit @Valid and enforce validation always. This is the way could make it:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44722000/how-to-spring-get-rid-of-validate-for-automatic-controller-validation