# How to: Spring get rid of @Validate for automatic Controller validation?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-aop, spring-validator

I know about `@Valid` annotation to instruct spring to validate for example a Controller argument according to JSR-303 in such this example:

```
@GetMapping("/test")
public TestDTO testDTO(@Valid TestDTO testDTO){
        return testDTO;
}
```

But I would like to be able to configure Spring in some way to enable validation in all my controllers without specify explicitly the `@Valid` annotation.

Is that possible in any way? Some Spring configuration? Making use of AOP?...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring MVC @Valid annotation for all controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26997281/spring-mvc-valid-annotation-for-all-controllers)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have finally came across with a working solution which may be not the optimal from the point of view of Spring configuration (as I said I'm Spring beginner).

The idea was to modify the argument resolvers (the ones that implement `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`), replacing the argument resolver associated to arguments with a `@RequestBody` annotation. Creating an inherited class from the default one (which is `RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor`) and overriding a method in the class hierarchy which efectively determines if perform a validation or not (based in the presence of `@Valid`, `@Validated`, `@ValidXxxxxx` annotations as the default behaviour), making to always validate with no further check.

So here is the code (I'm using Java 8 BTW):

Extend `RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor` to define validation strategy (in this case, always validate):

```
public class MyRequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor extends RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor {

    public MyRequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        super(converters);
    }

    @Override
    protected void validateIfApplicable(WebDataBinder binder, MethodParameter parameter) {
        binder.validate();      // always validating @RequestMapping annotated parameters ;)
    }
}
```

Define a `@Configuration` class where to replace default argument resolver:

```
@Configuration
public class MyValidationAdapterConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdapter;

    // Injecting your own resolver
    @Autowired
    private RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor requestResponseBodyMethodProcessor;


    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

        // Don't know why but, removing the target resolver and adding the injected one to the end does not work!
        // Must be something related with the resolvers ordering. So just replacing the target in the same position.
        final List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> mangledResolvers = requestMappingHandlerAdapter.getArgumentResolvers().stream()
            .map(resolver -> resolver.getClass().equals(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.class) ?
                requestResponseBodyMethodProcessor: resolver)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        requestMappingHandlerAdapter.setArgumentResolvers(mangledResolvers);
    }

}
```

Finally configure Spring to deliver your customized Bean in your Application configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:api.properties")
public class MyRestApiConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor requestResponseBodyMethodProcessor(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        return new MyRequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor(converters);
    }

}
```

Comment: looks nice. What will happen if validation fails?

Comment: In my case when validation fails a `MethodArgumentNotValidException` is thrown which I capture and handle it in `handleMethodArgumentNotValid`, an overriden method of `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`.

Comment: Thanks! However, how to automatically do it for those *non-RequestBody* items?

Answer (score 3):

unfortunately there is no "legal" way to do it.

Furthermore `@Valid` is not enough. You need also a `BindingResult` method parameter to be able to check the validation result: `bindingResult.hasErrors()`

If you don't want to use `BindingResult`, you could write your own Validator and throw an Exception in case of invalid input.

Comment: Thanks. And what about Aspects / Spring AOP? Wouldn't it be possible to achieve it that way? I'm learning Spring. Just want the developers doesn't have to worry about `@Valid`.

Comment: the `BindingResult` is not needed, depending on what you're building. 
For instance, if you respect the JSR303 and use `javax.validation` you can wrap everything in your `@ControllerAdvice` but I don't know if there is a way to force automatic validation

Comment: I found a way (don't know if legal or illegal) to make it work. See the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to do this however like Markus in the similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26997281/spring-mvc-valid-annotation-for-all-controllers) I'm not sure I agree its solving an actual problem.

Without getting too far into the weeds, Spring performs validation as part of model binding within [ModelAttributeMethodProcessor's](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/annotation/ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.html) validateIfApplicable method. Per the javadoc

> Validate the model attribute if applicable. The default implementation
>   checks for @javax.validation.Valid, Spring's Validated, and custom
>   annotations whose name starts with "Valid".

To override this functionality you need to create a custom ModelAttributeMethodProcessor / ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor. You then would need to register it as an argument resolver

```
public class ApplicationConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(final List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        // add your custom model attribute processor here
    }
}
```

Comment: No way I was able to achieve it with this mechanism but it gave me a hint of where to start looking how to do it. I've posted my solution which may not be the best way or option but the only I could make it to work.

Comment: @GerardB  Is there something specific you ran into that didn't work using this method?

Comment: Simply adding my resolver to `argumentResolvers` that way didn't work like if it was ignoring me. Don't even know if my resolver was actually added to the `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` who hosts resolvers; or my resolver is ignored because of the default one (`RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor`) matches first.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. This suggests that you are using the @RequestBody/@ResponseBody annotations correct?

Comment: Yes, I'm applying it in @RequestBody for DTO validation.

Comment: Great thanks. That wasn't in the original question and I'm interested in determining why the above doesn't work for that scenario.

Comment: If you figure it out, please, let me know.